# How do I connect pgAdmin to my PostgresDB that's running in Docker without changing the internal IP every time I restart the containers?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I've set up a local lab environment for learning Postgres. I'm using Docker Compose to run a postgres container and a pgAdmin instance next to each other. I can also successfully connect to the database server from pgAdmin's UI.

My only problem is that I can only manage to connect to the DB server using the internal IP of the postgres container as the host in the connection settings and this changes every time I restart my containers, so I have to check the new internal IP and manually update that on the UI of pgAdmin every time I restart my environment.

I've tried connecting using `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) and the exposed port but pgAdmin gives an error for that.

```
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 6543 failed:
Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 6543 failed: Address not available
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?127.0.0.1
```

I double check my running containers using `docker ps` and I see:

`25e9bfb30fe6   postgres         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   41 minutes ago   Up 41 minutes   0.0.0.0:6543->5432/tcp, :::6543->5432/tcp        sql-for-beginners_postgres_1`

So my postgres container is in fact exposed to the host on port `6543`.

Also if I run `telnet 127.0.0.1 6543` I get a successful connection. So then why can't I connect to it from pgAdmin using my host's IP?

I've also tried using `host.docker.internal` as the host in pgAdmin, but that also gives an error:

```
could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: Name does not resolve
```

The only way I could connect is via the internal IP, which is not persistent between stoping and staring the containers.

So my question is: Is there a way to set pgAdmin to a connection that will be persistent between container restarts?

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "6543:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: TEST_SM
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "5555:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Comment: Use the other container's Compose service name `postgres` and the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  In Docker each container is its own `localhost`, and connections between containers ignore `ports:`.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.